# Qt and GSM encoding

Tags: c++, qt, encoding, sms, pdu

Hi i am developping an open source sms application and i am using Qt. But now i have various problem with the encodings.
I am using this library for various pdu encoding and decoding https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdulib/
In gsm there 3 main encodings Default 7bit alphabet, UCS2 and 8bit data. So when For 7bit encoding the library expect std::string argument so i am passing it like this

```
QString message = lineEdit->toPlainText();
std::string msg_to_pass = message.toStdString();
```

The sms is correctly sended but when there is accent characters the sms arrives with bad characters like 'C?' the sign of bad charset/encoding. Note that it is the phone that show it. So decoding error is very low.

But when i am using the UCS2 encoding

```
QString message = lineEdit->toPlainText();
std::wstring msg_to_pass = message.toStdWString();
```

because the library requires std::wstring for UCS2 the characters with accent got printed well. But the problem is when i am decoding a sms received. I have modified function of this library to suit my needs but again characters with accent have a problem. Here is the function

```
template<class MsgT>
void PrintUserData(const MsgT& msg, QString &message)
{

    if (MsgT::DefaultAlphabet == msg.alphabet())
    {
        message = QString::fromStdString(msg.template userData<typename MsgT::DefaultUserData>().userData());
        std::cout << "User Data: " << msg.template userData<typename MsgT::DefaultUserData>().userData() << std::endl;
    }
    else if(MsgT::UCS2Alphabet == msg.alphabet())
    {
        QTextStream ts(stdout);
        message = QString::fromStdWString( msg.template userData<typename MsgT::UCS2UserData>().userData());
        qInfo()<< message;

        std::wcout << L"User Data: " << msg.template userData<typename MsgT::UCS2UserData>().userData() << std::endl;
    }
    else if(MsgT::EightBitDataAlphabet == msg.alphabet())
    {
        qInfo()<< "3";
        const std::vector<unsigned char>& data = msg.template userData<typename MsgT::EightBitUserData>().userData();
        std::cout << "User Data: ";
        PrintBinary(data.begin(), data.end());
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I have tested various pdu lib for C++ and this seems to be the best for me.
My think is that i am doing something bad with the std::string and std::wstring but i can't figure what.
Also i know that UCS2 is UTF-16 but i have read that there is small differences.
My locale is FR (French)
I am using Qt 5.9
Sorry for my english.

Comment: I suspect binding the text as `toPlainText();`  is wrong .. read text directly  `message = lineEdit->text();`

Comment: lineEdit here is a QTextEdit. I even try setting the sms body string directly in the code. there is always bad characters when it arrives to the receiver.

Comment: have you tried to format text as `QString::toUtf8()`

Comment: Qt docs say that QString is unicode by default. And yes i have tried it without success